# Display one row for value with multiple categories

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `games`. Each game belongs to one or more categories. I have a query that uses `GROUP BY category_id` but returns not the desired result. For the example below, `COD` belongs to three `category_id` but the query only shows for that specific game and omits other games with the same `category_id`. How can I achieve the below desired query?

**Query:**

```
SELECT *
FROM games
GROUP BY category_id
```

**Desired Result:**

```
+----------------+--------------------------+
|   game_name    |       category_id        |
+----------------+--------------------------+
| COD            | adventure, fighting, fps |
| Tekken         | fighting                 |
| Need for Speed | racing                   |
+----------------+--------------------------+
```

[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8341c6/1)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how did you make such a neat table?

Comment: Edit your question now and you will see how I did it.  It is possible to make it even nice than this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh ok, you did it manually? I thought maybe you used a "text to table" online tool. I have been looking for one.

Comment: Yes, I usually do it manually :-)  You get pretty fast after a while.  If you edit 500 posts, you will get a gold medal!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT function

```
SELECT
 game_name, GROUP_CONCAT(category_id) categories
FROM
  games
 GROUP BY 
 game_name;
```

Good luck!